# How do I get the id of an element when entering a function with $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the "id" of a clicked element but am having difficulties.

Here's what I'm trying to do in context. When `#display-p_1` is clicked:

```
<div id="display-p_1"> <a href='#content_div'> Panel 1</a></div>
```

I want to grab the "id" of the element, then strip off the last digit of the "id", assign it to an index, and run the function `runIt()`.

```
$(this).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  //this line isn't working
        n = id.slice(-1);
        runIt();  
    });
```

I think `$(this)` isn't referring to the right element within the function.

Comment: $(this).click(function() looks suspicious. What is "this" in this case?

Comment: For the record, in html4 an id should not contain a dash.

Comment: there are more elements that can be clicked?

Comment: That's a good point. I have an array of divs within another div that has id=navBar. I started out hard coding each id .... $(display-p_1).click(function() {... and so on, but I wanted to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[id^=display-p_]").on("click", function(){
    //stuff
});
```

This puts the click handler on all elements that have an id that starts with "display-p_"

[Relevant jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Since my answer has already been selected I'll edit it with @scunliffe's split() code as it is the better solution for that part.

```
$("[id^=display-p_]").on("click", function(){
    var divID = this.id;
    n = divID.split('_')[1];//this is assigning the string... use parseInt if you want a number
    runIt(n);//assuming you want to pass in the result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an element in your handler you can get the `id` in 2 ways:

I'm generically applying this to all `div` elements but you'd want to do this by a class or something.

```
$('div').click(function(){
  var fastAccessToID = this.id;
  var slowerAccessToID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

As for you hope to strip off the last digit... I think you want to get the number after the underscore.. e.g. "13" vs. "3" if the id was "display-p_13"?

thus...

```
$('div.someClass').click(function(){
  var divID = this.id;
  n = divID.split('_')[1];//this is assigning the string... use parseInt if you want a number
  runIt();
});
```

Comment: this doesn't explain why it's not working for the OP

Comment: tis interesting though. Is that because at that point "this" isn't already a jQuery object and calling "$(this)" creates it? Never seen this optimization before so curious as to the reasoning.

Comment: @lupos funny that you call plain javascript an optimization of jQuery ;-) You are correct, `$(this)` create the jQuery object.

Comment: @Christophe in the OP's question they were using `$(this).click...` to bind the event handler. I'm not sure if this was a bit of pseudo code but if not, `this` would have referred to the window object (thus still be valid), but when you try to extract the ID attribute it would fail.

Comment: @Christophe indeed! Though I find some of the best jQuery optimizations are to use pure JS. .each() for example. 

scunliffe I did not know $(this) would get the window. Good to know. Though from that you could do it "live" style $(this).on("click", "[id^=display-p_]", function(){});

Comment: @lupos yeah this is one of those questions where "the real answer is" comes into play... `.live()` is better, but then wait, that's deprecated so we should use `.on()` or `.deligate()`... which leads to the bigger question... wait, what are you trying to build because there is likely a better way to do the whole thing :-) and thus the real answer is... refactor... :-) (as for what $(this) is... `this` without context of a function/event handler etc. is the global window object.  Inside an event handler jQuery nicely makes it the element in question.